Is it possible to extra Year and Month from a datetime using date_part in postgresql?
So I have tried using date_part to extract the year from a datetime, and it works like a charm:
select date_part('year', (select min(t1.val) from tval t1 where t1.fid = 3771));

returns 2019
I would like to extract the year AND month from the datetime, is this possible?
For reference, the query select min(t1.val) from tval t1 where t1.fid = 3771 returns the datetime 2019-11-18 00:00:00.000
Even if it means creating a temporary new column to combine the year and month as strings that would be great. Struggling to this at the moment.

with dt as (select now() as now_dt) select date_part('year', now_dt) as year, date_part('month', now_dt) as month from dt;                                                                      year | month  ------+-------  2024 |     4

Thanks for the answer, actually the link above answered it too! :)
